# Prestashop site domain transfer

Tags: prestashop

i'm moving a prestashop site which was located on armarkat.biggo.org to armarkat.be. I searched all the tables in the db and change from armarkat.biggo.org to armarkat.be where possible. The prestashop config file has the base_url of "/". Site is conected to database.

Now the problem: If you visit http://armarkat.be you will notice that the site doesn't load. What could be the problem?

Greets.

Comment: what couldn't be the problem... you'll need to specify server configuration, specific site configuration, any errors you find in any logs. Does simple HTML serving work, does the domain name resolve correctly, etc.. This will also be better served on Serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is get an actual PHP Error message. The white page "of doom" is normally shown when errors are disabled from being sent server side to client side. You can normally check the errors file to get a list of what's going on, or enable errors temporarily to see.

You can normally enable error access using .htaccess if your hosting provider allows it

```
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log
```

Comment: So what exactly happens here? In the public_html of the site here is no PHP_errors.log located. Is it going to create one?

Comment: This would create a log in the public_html folder yes. Your host may already have logging switched on and logging to a different folder I honestly don't know. With this, if your host allows .htaccess overrides then this will just create a log in the location specified.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!
In tools -> Configuration information the **Required parameters** were not fulfilled. I had to give write permission to some of the folders :)